# Ensuring client updates to latest api version

Tags: rest, api, versioning, restful-architecture

I'm learning about the REST architecture style, and there are some things I don't understand when it comes to developing a back-end api for clients.

I've read about various approaches to versioning an http api, which all make sense, but how do you indicate to a client, when he's using an outdated version of your api, that he needs to update his version? Is there a way to do this without physically contacting the client and telling him that he needs to update his version?

I was thinking there might be some way to require the client to indicate his current version and give an appropriate message if it's outdated. Is this standard or even feasible?

Comment: This is a broad issue. You can search for "api versioning" and find lots of ideas, including right here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, clients update under one of two circumstances. Either they want functionality that's available in a more recent version, or you're dropping support for a prior version.

If you're planning on dropping support for an API version, you should definitely be notifying any customers you can find proactively. If they rely on your API version, and it disappears with no warning, they're going to be former customers.

In the vast majority of cases, clients of your API will not be scanning network traffic looking for a header or other indicator that the API is changing. Asking them to do so is non-standard and almost certainly not feasible.

Also, dropping support for an API version is a major shift. It causes upheaval in all of your clients, forcing them to make a code change in their applications by a date of your choice. It's not something to be done lightly.